# What inverted chord is this?

Tags: piano, chords

What chord is this? I thought maybe E(add2)/B?

[image]

**The top line is treble and the bottom is bass**

Comment: Does this music have a key signature?

Comment: Yes, the music is in D major

Comment: What made you think it's inverted?

Answer (score 3):

In the key of D, as suggested by comments, this chord is a Bsus4, with B-B-B-E-F♯, where the minor 3rd of the vi chord (D of Bm) has been replaced by the 4th (E).

With so many Bs in the spelling, I would be inclined to call this chord a Bsus4, but it may also be an inversion of an Esus2, where the minor 3rd of the ii chord (G of Em) has been replaced by the 2nd (F♯).

Comment: Did you mean 'the minor 3rd of the vi chord '? And while it probably would be Bm rather than B, but without the 3rd, it's better calling it Bsus4. Bmsus4 can't exist, I'd have thought. +1

Comment: And there's always the possibility of xsus4 being (dom)xsus2, although with all those Bs, it's unlikely here.

Comment: Yes, I did mean vi; corrected. I didn't mean to suggest Bmsus4, just connecting the chord to its likely diatonic counterpart.

Comment: I understand, although Aric has more than hinted at that.

Answer (score 1):

*(I assume there is no key signature.)*

First of all, we can safely assume that the root note is B, since it is played in three different octaves. The other notes are E and F.

The dominant note in B is F#, meaning that this must be a diminished chord. The E is the subdominant note in B minor, so this chord would be a suspension of the fourth.

**There is, of course, another *less likely* possibility**

It is most likely that this is a diminished chord with a suspension, however it's also possible that this is E with a suspension (Esus2).

In second inversion, this has the correct notes to be a suspended second chord on E (B E <strike>G</strike> F), however the G is missing.

**In resonse to the OP's comment**

This is actually in the key of D major / B minor:

[image]

The notes of this chord are B, E, and F#. **This is a B minor chord with a suspension** on the fourth (some might call it Bsus4).

Comment: Without an indication of clefs, you cannot actually assume those notes are B's

Comment: @NeilMeyer the bold text in the question says what the clefs are.

Comment: Oops. Forgot to put that this is in D major.